# axios get, put, post method request failed with status code 403

Tags: node.js, express, axios

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (C:\Yatin\API\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Yatin\API\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Yatin\API\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

When I execute following code in the function, it shows above error. Until some time it was working perfectly fine but suddenly it is not working now.

```
var azureREST_listContainerURI = <URL_that is generated here by calling other functions>
axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: azureREST_listContainerURI
          })
           .then(function (response) {

            parser.parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
                if(err) throw err
              for(let containerObj of result.EnumerationResults.Containers[0].Container)
              {
                  var containerobject = {
                      "Name":containerObj['Name'][0],
                      "properties":{
                          "last_modified":containerObj['Properties'][0]['Last-Modified'][0]
                          }
                      }
                      customJSONResponse['containers'].push(containerobject);
              }
              res.send(customJSONResponse) 
           })
          })
           .catch(function (error) {
           res.send({error:error})
           console.log(error.stack)
            console.log("Error while calling Azure REST endpoint : " + error);
           });
```

This does not work and shows above error, Although when I try executing the same code by hard coding the url parameter in axios.get within single quotes it works absolutely fine.

Comment: Do you run this inside a (local) webserver or do you open the file directly? Have you checked the contents of the `azureREST_listContainerURI` variable?

Comment: I run it inside the local webserver and the content of the variable is perfectly fine because when i log it to console the URL return the result